Block Windows With WPF Application
I need to develop a WPF application (Windows Form) similar to a cyber-cafe app. When a specified time elapses or a particular event occurs, I require the application to display a login prompt and restrict window navigation shortcuts such as Alt + Tab, Windows + D, etc.
I used:
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool LockWorkStation();

But the user not wants Like (Windows + L) he wants a custom loggin, but Restrict the navigation on windows.

Does this answer your question? Form that locks UI

I've developed "kiosks" using touchscreens and no keyboard (or mouse). You can lock down a PC if that's the plan. Slide in an opaque panel over any content for effect, etc.

Thank you, "Form that locks UI" may be work
